# Save Custom Data in Thingsboard ; Which is not a Telemetry data

Tags: javascript, angular, angularjs, thingsboard

I am using `thingsboard`.

Lets say i have a simple `User` Form having the following attributes:

Username
First Name
Last Name
Email
Address
Phone Number

Now i want to save all these details in thingsboard. Is that possible in thingsboard? If yes, any help is appreciated.

Answer (score 1):

Yes.

You can save any object that is not a device (which does not transmit its own telemetry) as an [Asset](https://thingsboard.io/docs/pe/user-guide/ui/assets/), therefore you can save object attributes as [Asset attributes](https://thingsboard.io/docs/pe/user-guide/ui/assets/#asset-attributes)

Answer (score 0):

yes. you can save any kind of object, there is a multiple choice(customers, assets, dashboards ..) after creating the object you can save any attributes related to it.